# Work part time for new job before joining full time

Tags: new-job, negotiation, part-time

I need to give one month's notice before I can leave my current job. A potential employer is in a hurry for me to join asap. He has asked if I can work part time before I join full time so I can get up to speed. Is this a good idea to do and how should compensation be?

Comment: Part time? How, you work all day for one place then go to another?

Comment: Seems you follow me around haha. They want me up to speed so when I'm starting full time for them I can hit the ground running. They are quite swamped for work and need someone asap.

Comment: At what time? After hours? You have a full time job....

Comment: Basically after work, head over there and get caught up with the codebase, developers, product, and whatever else. Right now my job is quite stable. Typical 9-6pm time frame.

Comment: Will the first company have a problem with this? Please mention your country. Also is the one month notice by law, contract, or tradition?

Comment: It's the norm in my country to have one month notice. Good question about first company. Haven't asked cause I haven't received and accepted the offer but it was just something to keep in mind cause they have mentioned this to me as something they would desire.

Comment: Honestly, I'm seeing red flags with this new job, specifically, the boss. If you're not worried and think the pay is fine, sure, why not? But I wouldn't overextend myself. Safety and health come first.

Comment: Good point. Can you tell me about the red flags?

Comment: RED FLAG: All of your new co-workers are going to still be in the office from 6-10pm every day! Think long and hard about whether or not you want to work from 9am-10pm+ every day (If they're working 13+ hour days during the week, they're probably there on weekends too). Some people live to work, and if you want to devote yourself to your work, that's your call, but you damn well better be overly compensated for it.

Comment: Good point. That may be true. Or it may just be the founders and they want me to get to know the system some more before joining full time. Would be good to know what would be the "part time". Would like to ask.

Comment: @ChrisG Not necessarily. Ask about the normal work schedule at the place before you join.

Comment: Asked. He said they are working late cause of a deadline. But normally 9-6. He gives them half day on Friday to make up for it with weekends off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a good idea to do and how should compensation be?

If you have the time, it can be a great idea.

Your new employer can get a bit of help during a crunch time and you can hit the ground running when you join full time. You can make a bit of extra money, and gather a lot of goodwill by showing you are willing to put in extra effort.

I've done this before. I was hired into an IT management position. During my 2-week notice period, I spent nights and weekends and designed the layout of a new mainframe computer room. In my case, I asked for no compensation.

In your case, assuming you aren't going into upper management, you should ask for your normal new salary, prorated to match the hours you actually work.

Be sure that this is all laid out in writing beforehand, and not just as an informal promise. Make sure taxes are withheld, etc. Make sure the expectations as to your time commitment are clear - that both sides know how much of your free time you can spend.

Comment: It is a somewhat upper management role. But not sure how much up it is. :) thanks for your experience and input. It aligns with what I was thinking, actually.

Comment: This is the same company that 'made a mistake' with the salary range, now pressuring to start early as part time.... I'd be very careful

Comment: @Kilisi good point about that. Would need to think about this

Comment: @JoeStrazzere indeed. Well I mean I haven't decided yet and why would management be different than non management? If they are taking time from you then shouldn't you be compensated for your time?

Comment: @Allen my experience matches up with Joe's on his comment above.

Comment: Amen on that, @JoeStrazzere. They're typically asking me to pick up after hours work as I think they're grooming me for future promotion (which I'm dodging as long as humanly possible, thankyouverymuch).